# Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes for Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, security, kibana, cluster-computing, elk

I have written a docoker-compose to up ELK,but when I run it i get

> ```
> Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes
> ```

from my kibana container!

Here is my structure:
first my compoese is like it:

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch-core:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.1
    container_name: ${NODE_NAME}-es
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: ${NODE_NAME}-es
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 131072
        hard: 131072
      nproc: 8192
      fsize: -1
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 9200:9200/tcp
      - 9300:9300/tcp
    volumes:
      - $PWD/Elasticsearch-TOR/var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - $PWD/Elasticsearch-TOR/etc/certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms12g -Xmx12g'
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      cluster.name: elk
      node.name: ${NODE_NAME}-es
      bootstrap.memory_lock: 'true'
      network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
      network.publish_host: ${NETWORK_PUBLISH_HOST}
      http.port: 9200
      http.publish_port: 9200
      transport.port: 9300
      transport.publish_port: 9300
      discovery.seed_hosts: '${ELK_HOSTS_1},${ELK_HOSTS_2},${ELK_HOSTS_3}'
      cluster.initial_master_nodes: 'ELK_NODE_1-es,ELK_NODE_2-es,ELK_NODE_3-es'
      indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 8192
      search.max_buckets: 250000
      action.destructive_requires_name: 'true'
      reindex.remote.whitelist: '*:*'
      reindex.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
      xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.key
      xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.pem
      xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/root-ca-key.pem
      xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
      xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: 'true'
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.key
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.pem
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/root-ca-key.pem
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: 'false'
      xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: 'true'
      xpack.monitoring.collection.interval: 30s
      xpack.security.enabled: 'true'
      xpack.security.audit.enabled: 'false'

  kibana-ui:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.13.1
    container_name: ${NODE_NAME}-kibana-ui
    restart: always
    hostname: ${NODE_NAME}-kibana-ui
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 5601:5601/tcp
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    environment:
      TELEMETRY_OPTIN: 'false'
      TELEMETRY_ENABLED: 'false'
      NEWSFEED_ENABLED: 'false'
      SERVER_NAME: ${NODE_NAME}-kibana-ui
      SERVER_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
      SERVER_PORT: 5601
      SERVER_MAXPAYLOADBYTES: 8388608
      ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINTS: '["https://172.31.44.131:9200","https://172.31.44.132:9200","https://172.31.44.133:9200"]'
      ELASTICSEARCH_USER: ${ELASTIC_USER}
      ELASTICSEARCH_SECRET: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      ES_REQUEST_TIMEOUT: 132000
      ES_SHARD_TIMEOUT: 120000
      # ES_SSL_CERT: /etc/kibana/certs/ui/ui.crt
      # ES_SSL_KEY: /etc/kibana/certs/ui/ui.key
      # ES_SSL_CA: /etc/kibana/certs/ca/ca.crt
      ES_SSL_VERIFY: 'none'
      KIBANA_SUGGEST_TIMEOUT: 3000
      KIBANA_SUGGEST_LIMIT: 2500000
      VEGA_ALLOW_URLS: 'true'
      XPACK_MAPS_AVAILABLE_VISUALS: 'true'
      XPACK_SECURITY_ENCRYPTIONKEY: 'MyEncryptionKey_0123456789_0123456789_0123456789'
      XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY: 'aCSQOG1/q6Mzo+myAyjslONJtC7rNgc0VhsZHZfyWTA='
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch-core

  logstash-worker:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.13.1
    container_name: ${NODE_NAME}-logstash-agent
    restart: always
    hostname: ${NODE_NAME}-logstash-agent
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
    volumes:
      - $PWD/logstash/configurations:/usr/share/logstash/config
      - $PWD/logstash/data-flow:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline
#      - $PWD/logstash/configurations:/usr/share/logstash/config
    environment:
#      JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms256m -Xmx2g'
      XPACK_STATS: 'false'
      XPACK_CTRL: 'false'
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch-core
    links:
      - elasticsearch-core
```

also here is my .env

```
    cat .env
    ELASTIC_USER=elastic
    ELASTIC_PASSWORD=xxxxx
    NODE_NAME=ELK_NODE_1
    NETWORK_PUBLISH_HOST=172.31.44.131
    ELK_HOSTS_1=172.31.44.131
    ELK_HOSTS_2=172.31.44.132
    ELK_HOSTS_3=172.31.44.133
```

here is my stracture directories:

```
tree .
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Elasticsearch-TOR
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── etc
│   │   └── certs
│   │       ├── cert-gen.sh
│   │       ├── node.key
│   │       ├── node.pem
│   │       ├── root-ca-key.pem
│   │       ├── root-ca.pem
│   │       └── root-ca.srl
│   └── var
│       └── lib
│           └── elasticsearch
│               └── nodes
│                   └── 0
│                       ├── node.lock
│                       ├── snapshot_cache
│                       │   ├── segments_1
│                       │   └── write.lock
│                       └── _state
│                           ├── _0.cfe
│                           ├── _0.cfs
│                           ├── _0.si
│                           ├── manifest-0.st
│                           ├── node-0.st
│                           ├── segments_1
│                           └── write.lock
├── env-sample
├── kibana
│   └── kibana.yml
├── kibana-7.12.x-codex-dark.ndjson
├── logstash
│   ├── configurations
│   │   ├── jvm.options
│   │   ├── log4j2.properties
│   │   └── logstash.yml
│   └── data-flow
│       └── pipeline.conf
```

also here is my kibana.yml

```
> cat kibana/kibana.yml
> #server.port: 5601
> #server.host: "0.0.0.0" elasticsearch.preserveHost: true kibana.index: ".kibana" elasticsearch.username: kibana_system
> elasticsearch.password: xxxxx
> elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: "none"
```

and this is my logstash.yml and log4j2.properties and jvm.options

```
> cat log4j2.properties status = error name = LogstashPropertiesConfig
> 
> appender.console.type = Console appender.console.name = plain_console
> appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
> appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c]
> %-.10000m%n
> 
> rootLogger.level = info rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref =
> plain_console
```

```
 cat logstash.yml

    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
```

```
cat jvm.options

    ## JVM configuration
    
    # Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
    # Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space
    
    -Xms1g
    -Xmx1g
    
    ################################################################
    ## Expert settings
    ################################################################
    ##
    ## All settings below this section are considered
    ## expert settings. Don't tamper with them unless
    ## you understand what you are doing
    ##
    ################################################################
    
    ## GC configuration
    11-13:-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
    11-13:-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
    11-13:-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
    
    ## Locale
    # Set the locale language
    #-Duser.language=en
    
    # Set the locale country
    #-Duser.country=US
    
    # Set the locale variant, if any
    #-Duser.variant=
    
    ## basic
    
    # set the I/O temp directory
    #-Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME
    
    # set to headless, just in case
    -Djava.awt.headless=true
    
    # ensure UTF-8 encoding by default (e.g. filenames)
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    
    # use our provided JNA always versus the system one
    #-Djna.nosys=true
    
    # Turn on JRuby invokedynamic
    -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true
    
    ## heap dumps
    
    # generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails
    # heap dumps are created in the working directory of the JVM
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    
    # specify an alternative path for heap dumps
    # ensure the directory exists and has sufficient space
    #-XX:HeapDumpPath=${LOGSTASH_HOME}/heapdump.hprof
    
    ## GC logging
    #-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=@loggc@:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
    
    # log GC status to a file with time stamps
    # ensure the directory exists
    #-Xloggc:${LS_GC_LOG_FILE}
    
    # Entropy source for randomness
    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom
    
    # Copy the logging context from parent threads to children
    -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true
```

my container status for logstash is up!but in browser for http I get

> Kibana server is not ready yet

and for https I get

```
> Secure Connection Failed An error occurred during a connection to
> 172.31.44.131:5601. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG The page
> you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the
> received data could not be verified. Please contact the website owners
> to inform them of this problem.
```

I have ping and curl from kibana container to elastichsearch container,and there is no network or firewall problem!